# Difference between the source codes of SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm learning SpringMVC via Mkyong.com.

When i download the source code from [Mkyong.com website](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4n7qG7UtkgsbEVkQko4eE1wWTg&usp=sharing) -- code runs correctly.

And the code does on myself is not working properly(not using MAVEN as per in tutorial)

is not using MAVEN is wrong for not getting output.

Please help me to get output for my source code too.

- Here is my source code [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4n7qG7UtkgsTllYTVBwTnpjaTA&usp=sharing):
- I often getting error is "No DispatcherServlet Mapping found with name "mvc-dispatcher"...."

  -the libraries i used :

[image]

Comment: Post relevant block of xml from your web.xml and mvc-dispatcher*.xml

Comment: @SajanChandran i given the link of my source code.Please look at that and give me answer.

Comment: check your final WAR file, it should contain all the necessary jar files, see WAR/WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier - use Maven.

If you are learning Spring / MVC, I would suggest you to use [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts) IDE. It has many Spring and Maven friendly features.

For example, to get a working Spring MVC project:-

File -> New -> Other -> Spring Project -> Spring MVC Project.

The embedded Maven will take care of all the dependencies versions.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not using maven, then you have to download and register the required libaries (dependencies) by your own.

Every libary that is needed at runtime (and not alredy included in the server like `servlet-api`) needs to be stored in `/WEB-INF/lib/`

---

*It is a time consuming task to find and download all the needed libaries, I would recommend that you spend this time in trying to get maven run.*

Comment: @ Ralph :I already added all my jar in lib folder becoz of not using Maven .Please see my edited question

Comment: It is not in the uploaded example. Did you removed it before uploading?

Answer (score 1):

Using Maven is exactly the solution for the pain you are facing. Another advantage with Maven would be that you can easily change your library version and all the related correct dependencies would be downloaded. If you want to try out some new feature in latest releases of Spring MVC (or any other library for that matter) you need to just change the version instead of downloading all the dependent versions manually.